# Why this doesnt fire ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, javascript, angularjs-ng-repeat, pubnub

**My HTML**

`ng-app` and `ng-controller` are specified in markup earlier

```
<div class="statusEntry" ng-repeat="statusInput in statusInputs">
 <span class="userName"> a </span>                
 <span  class="statusMsg"> b </span>                
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('globalCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
//someWork
pubnub.subscribe({
channel: "statuses",
callback:
function (data) {

    splitData = data.split(';');
    prepData = '{'+splitData[0]+','+splitData[1]+'}';
    statusInputs.push(prepData);
}
});
```

When I push the data no new object appears.

Comment: Are you assigning statusInputs to the controller scope?

Comment: Could the problem be that this function is called from within PubNub ?

Comment: Where is the `ng-init`?

Comment: i dont have ng-init in the markup anywhere, on ng-init the array is empty.

Comment: @DanielBeck Im afraid not, but i dont know how to check it. Sorry if this is stupid question but i am just starting with Angular and already getting stuck

Comment: what does `{{statusInputs|json}}` display?  If it's not there, it is a problem getting your data nd you should close and reword your question since it has nothing to do with Angular and ng-repeat

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Looks like you're right. Any hint about how should i ask the correct question ? Should i ask "how to call angular function from pubnub" ?

Comment: I've never used `pubnub` but I'm guessing it's a problem with that.  Put `console.log` statements to make sure that's getting executed and your controller is getting loaded.  Try the `pubnub.subscribe` on its own and put a `console.log` in the callback to see that you're getting the data.  Check the `network` tab in chrome to see if any data is flowing.  With that info you can narrow down what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your Controller has no name.
2. You haven't declare an `ng-app` or `ng-controller` in your markup anywhere.
3. `data` should be named `$scope` so Angular can appropriately inject the dependency.
4. It doesn't look like either `statusInputs` or your function are part of the `$scope` therefore there's no way for your view to access them.

Comment: I only posted the function that works with the array, it is inside otherwise working controller

Comment: @Slytherin - It would be helpful if you posted a working example then. There's no telling what the problem might be in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
statusInputs.push(prepData);
```

with

```
$scope.statusInputs.push(prepData);
```

This is how you enable your views to access them.

Comment: `$scope.statusInputs` is undefined.

Comment: initiate with $scope.statusInputs = [] before the function call to pub nub.subscrite